# Как настроить гит хуки и для инструментов, которые обеспечивают GUI для Git?

Tags: git, githooks

В проекте используется линтер (eslint), зацепленный на commit с помощью [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky). Если есть хоть одна ошибка - коммит абортится. Чуть позже сюда добавится ещё прогон unit тестов.

Если работать с Git через терминал, то хук работает. А вот если коммитить через, например, UI в IDE (WebStorm, VS Code), то можно закоммитить всё что угодно без проверки линтера.

Как мне настроить Git так, чтобы хуки там работали для любого использования?

Comment: Git хуки поддерживаются с нативным git "из коробки", но для поддержки хуков в IDE нужно смотреть документацию по конкретной IDE. Лучше добавлять проверки/тесты/и т.д. в CI скрипты и выполнять их на Git сервере, тогда это будет работать в любых случаях/вариантах. Посмотрите в сторону установки расширения для eslint, которое Вы будете запускать локально.

Comment: @XelaNimed, Спасибо! Хостим на GitHub. Сильно подозреваю, что там можно настроить хуки с помощью actions? Или, хотя бы, PR?

Comment: Хуки - это про локальное окружение, т.е. они будут работать только на конкретной машине. Если предполагается, что проект будут разрабатывать несколько разработчиков, то нужно настраивать CI-скрипт, pipelines, SonarQube, и т.д. на стороне Git-сервера. Только такой подход будет гарантировать, что код соответствует определённым метрикам/правилам/качеству.